# Issues replacing new line in PowerShell script

Tags: file, powershell, csv, replace, newline

I have a CSV file which has the following for example:

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5
,,,,,
data6,data7,data8,data9,data0
```

New lines are CRLF (`` `r`n ``) as viewed in Notepad++.

I have this in my PowerShell script to remove the line with all commas:

`` (Get-Content $csvPath) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace ",,,,,`r`n", ""} | Set-Content $csvPath2 ``

The script will not detect the returns. Even if I remove the commas and just have `` `r`n ``. However, I can replace the commas with `` `r`n `` without issues.

How can I remove that entire line of commas so that it appears as below?

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5
data6,data7,data8,data9,data0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$lines = get-content C:\temp\test.txt | ?{$_ -notlike ",,,,*"}
$lines.count
```

Here the file test.txt contains:

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5
,,,,
data6,data7,data8,data9,data0
```

The output is:

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5
data6,data7,data8,data9,data0
```

Comment: Knows Not Much is correct. The reason why your original attempt wasn't working is that by default, Get-Content returns an array of strings, with the delimiter being a line break. So when you pipe it to ForEach-Object, none of the individual lines will have a line break in it. Alternately, if you really want to use the -replace method, add the -Raw parameter to the Get-Content cmdlet (or use -ReadCount 0 if you're on PowerShell 2 or lower).

Comment: Thank you both very much.  The solution from Knows Not Much worked.  And @KevinD thank you for the explanation.  It makes sense as to why it was not working.  I appreciate your assistance!